# Что это за алгоритм (GOST)?

Tags: java, алгоритм, криптография

Встретился вопрос: как реализовать алгоритм GOST?

Что за GOST алгоритм? Гуглятся только ГОСТы.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_%28block_cipher%29

Answer (score 7):

Есть ГОСТ 28147-89 и ГОСТ 34.12-2015. Это ГОСТы на криптографическую защиту информаци.

Answer (score 7):

GOST это советский симметричный блочный шифр рассекреченный еще в 80-х годах. Можно [почитать в википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2_28147-89) есть ее новая инкарнация от 2015 года известная под названием [Кузнечик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80))

Имеется довольно много ее реализаций, в частности он реализован в известном криптопакете [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/)

Исходников на различных языках [много](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=gost+cipher&type=)